# Dynamic meta tags in server side using react

Tags: reactjs, express, meta-tags, server-side-rendering

I am building a React app with SSR. I now have to implement a Facebook share feature with dynamic meta tags(og:title and og:image).

After reading this tutorial, https://www.kapwing.com/blog/how-to-add-dynamic-meta-tags-server-side-with-create-react-app/, I could finish my `/about` and `/faq` pages(static). However, I have a problem on dynamic pages such as `/posts/:id`.

In `public/index.html`, I replace the metadata with an identifiable string:

```
<!-- in public/index.html -->
<title>$OG_TITLE</title>
<meta name="description"        content="$OG_DESCRIPTION" />
<meta property="og:title"       content="$OG_TITLE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION" />
<meta property="og:image"       content="$OG_IMAGE" />
```

And then on the server, I replace these strings with the dynamically generated information. Here is an example route with Node and Express:

```
app.get('/about', function(request, response) {
  console.log('About page visited!');
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './build', 'index.html')
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, 'About Page');
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_DESCRIPTION/g, "About page description");
    result = data.replace(/\$OG_IMAGE/g, 'https://i.imgur.com/V7irMl8.png');
    response.send(result);
  });
});
```

So for dynamic routes, `/posts/:id`, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The same as `/about`

```
app.get('/posts/:id', function(request, response) {...}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).